# Newbie - getting started with applications in Heroku site

Tags: python, heroku

I have an application that basically "listen" to API calls (flask) and run a script based on the input.

I now confused which models do I need to use? 
A   one worker app and one web app
B.   One web+worker

I'm asking it because of pricing and sleeping cases. 
The project basically just waiting for a POST request 24/7 and executes python code.

Do I need to split it into two like described here? 
https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-build-a-task-notification-bot-for-slack-with-python-part-4-hosting-and-testing-cc2c727a67e6

Or leave it as a single worker/web app

Excuse me, Daniel,

I was just redirected from Heroku site here, so I was sure this question will be an easy one to expertise.

I am working according to the [LINK](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-build-a-task-notification-bot-for-slack-with-python-part-4-hosting-and-testing-cc2c727a67e6) I sent before.

In his steps, ( number 3 ), he explained:

> Add a file named Procfile in the root of your project folder. We will add the >following snippets in the file. It will be used by heroku to start our >application running on a web server( gunicorn) and webhook running on a heroku >worker. 
>   **web: gunicorn ranti:app
>   worker: python worker.py**

My code is below:

```
from config import get_env
from app import create_app


app = create_app(get_env('APP_ENV'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The route is the below:

```
    def index():
        return "WORKING"

    @app.route('/todo', methods=['POST'])
    def abc():
        print(request.json)
        email = request.json['email']
        ticket_id = request.json['ticket_id']
        message1 = Psycopg2Helper.sql_query1(email, sql_user, sql_password, sql_db, sql_host_eu)
        if not message1:
            message1 = Psycopg2Helper.sql_query1(email, sql_user, sql_password, sql_db, sql_host_us)
        if not message1:
            message1 = Psycopg2Helper.sql_query1(email, sql_user, sql_password, sql_db, sql_host_ap)
        text_to_zd = ZenDesk.edit(message1)
        ZenDesk.put_comment(ticket_id, text_to_zd, zd_user, zd_password)
        return email
```

The classes file just make comments via API to different sites. ( PUT commands )

So, my question, Do I need to split my app into two? a WEB and a WORKER as the link explained, or I shall use only one WEB file ( my case: main_app.py: )

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about here. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

- You need to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: Excuse me, Daniel,

I was just redirected from Heroku site here, so I was sure this question will be an easy one to expertise.

I am working according to the [LINK](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-build-a-task-notification-bot-for-slack-with-python-part-4-hosting-and-testing-cc2c727a67e6) I sent before.